# TestCafe: How to use disableMultipleWindows inside "test" function?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to disable multiple windows on a specific test only. And I found this option "disableMultipleWindows". But how to use this option inside the test function?

```
test('test', async t => {
    // How to apply this option or similar inside this function?
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `--disableMultipleWindows` option is applied to the set of tests and cannot be applied to a single test or fixture.

Could you please elaborate on why you need to disable this functionality only for a specific test?

Comment: There are tests like clicking on a button then opens a new window which is fine. I have this 1 test that when you click the download button, it opens a new window, a blank window. If I disable the multiple window then no issue. So I decided to disable it on this specific test only.

Comment: We have a similar issue at [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5574](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5574) However, I cannot say for sure that the cause is the same. Could you please create a sample or give us the URL to your site? Please share this information in the context of a GitHub issue. In this case, we will be able to process it more effectively.